# How to reduce the tabular row space in awesome-cv mode

Tags: spacing

I want the space between:

1. the "Deutsche Bank" column and "Summer analyst" column to be smaller
2. the "Deutsche Bank" column and "business loans..." column to be smaller
   [image]
   I already tried   \def\arraystretch{0.88} but it doesn't work.
   I was using the tabular function as shown below

You may find the initial codes through:
https://www.overleaf.com/10585538rcwmgzkhrzrx#/39579324/
where you click the folder "resume" and find "awesome-cv.cls": its lines 172-184 I believe can be changed.
And you find "resume.tex": its lines 187-217 are printed in the screenshot.

Or these codes (but they don't seem to looks well in some environments, hence I would suggest directly clicking the link and find the initial codes, thanks):

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper]{awesome-cv}
\geometry{left=0.4cm, top=.3cm, right=0.4cm, bottom=0cm, footskip=0cm}

\newcommand*{\cventry}[5]{%
  \def\arraystretch{0.88}
  \vspace{-2.2mm}
  \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
  \setlength{\extrarowheight}{0pt}
  \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} L{\textwidth - 4.5cm} R{4.5cm}}
    \ifempty{#2#3}
      {\entrypositionstyle{#1} & \entrydatestyle{#4} \\}
      {\entrytitlestyle{#2} & \entrylocationstyle{#3} \\
      \entrypositionstyle{#1} & \entrydatestyle{#4} \\}
    \multicolumn{2}{L{\textwidth}}{\descriptionstyle{#5}}
  \end{tabular*}%
}

\cvsection{Work Experience}
\begin{cventries}
%---------------------------------------------------------
  \cventry
    {Summer Analyst, Corporate Finance Dept.} % Role
    {ICBC} % Title
    {\color{black} {Beijing, China}} % Location
    {06-08/2016} % Date(s)
    {
      \begin{cvitems} % Description(s)
        \item {Assisted the sales team in product analysis for 4 quarters and compared net profit of clearing, investment banking, internet financing, collaborating, and wealth management services}
        \item {Collated and analyzed data of world demography, China’s macro policies and capital return rate by industry; concluded 5 factors that have influence on bond market}
        \item {Participated in 3 client negotiation meetings with a state-owned corporation; framed memos, identified cooperation opportunities by releasing co-branded credit cards and share our customers’ points}
        \item {Compiled a one billion bond-raising book for a state-owned AA+ hydroelectric company to supplement operating cash flow and replace business loans; advised to launch in Sep, 2016 at a lower interest rate}
      \end{cvitems}
    }

  \cventry
    {Summer Analyst, Corporate Finance Dept.} % Role
    {Deutsche Bank} % Title
    {\color{black} {Beijing, China}} % Location
    {07/2016} % Date(s)
    {
      \begin{cvitems} % Description(s)
        \item {Assisted the sales team in product analysis for 4 quarters and compared net profit of clearing, investment banking, internet financing, collaborating, and wealth management services}
        \item {Collated and analyzed data of world demography, China’s macro policies and capital return rate by industry; concluded 5 factors that have influence on bond market}
        \item {Participated in 3 client negotiation meetings with a state-owned corporation; framed memos, identified cooperation opportunities by releasing co-branded credit cards and share our customers’ points}
        \item {Compiled a one billion bond-raising book for a state-owned AA+ hydroelectric company to supplement operating cash flow and replace business loans; advised to launch in Sep, 2016 at a lower interest rate}
      \end{cvitems}
    }
%---------------------------------------------------------
\end{cventries}
\end{document}
```

Thank you in advance for your techniques and kindness.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. Please don't add your code as a screenshot, but as text, so we copy it and don't have to retype it.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot test your above code (even after adding `\begin{document}` and changing the `\newcommand` to `\renewcommand` I cannot compile it without errors), but maybe you could manually adjust the spacing by replacing \\ with `\\[-0.5cm]`?

Comment: Hello Sam, replacing \\ with \\[-0.5cm] works perfectly in the awesome-cv environment! Thank you sooooo much for helping me!

Answer (score 3):

To decrease the space between two rows, a quick and dirty way could be to manually add some negative space by replacing

```
\\
```

with

```
\\[-0.5cm]
```

Comment: @DarcyPu Good to hear that the answer helped you. If you are satisfied with the solution, please consider accepting it (by clicking on the checkmark ✓, see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows others that the question is solved and will remove it from the list of unanswered questions. As a bonus, this will not only give a reward to the answer, but you will get 2 reputation points, too.